# AWS CodeDeploy ymal file error

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-code-deploy

I am deploying an application using AWS code deploy to Windows environment. I use an apspec.yml yaml file. When I deploy the application I get following error

**The deployment failed because an invalid version value () was entered in the application specification file. Make sure your AppSpec file specifies "0.0" as the version, and then try again.**

It seems like there is a problem with encoding or line ending. All the materials in the internet are for linux but not for windows. I use visual studio editor to edit this file.  How to fix this issue?

Comment: i am facing same proble still let me know if there is any solution
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62613077/aws-code-deploy-ec2-on-premises-yml-file-error-on-from-s3-to-windows-server

Answer (score 5):

In my case the encoding was wrong. `appspec.yml` should be saved as `UTF-8` and not `UTF-8 BOM`.

**BTW**: The encoding can be changed in VS 2017 using `File > Save as..`, then the down arrow at the *Save*-Button ... *Save with encoding...*

Answer (score 3):

The issue is in the line ending. If you create a yml file make sure you use \n line ending (linux way of line ending) instead of \r\n (windows way of line ending). If your editor is visual studio when you safe the yml file save it as follows. 
File->Advanced Saved Options

[image]

Comment: YAML has had generic line breaks in all its incarnations (1.0/1.1/1.2) for 15+ years. If you really have to deal with software that process YAML and needs specific line-endings, you should look for an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your appspec.yml starts with below line

```
version: 0.0
```

codedeploy requires this attribute as must. refer [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-structure.html)

Answer (score 0):

Change the Encoding format by simply opening it notepad++ from UTF-8-BOM to UTF-8

[image]