# AWS Code Deploy EC2/On-premises yml file error on from s3 to windows server

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy, aws-code-deploy-appspec

i am struggling since 2 days, but i can not find proper answer, and also in google there are no refrence that i can solve error.

1. what i have did i have created deployment in aws code deploy, have attach role with awscodeeployrole,
2. created zip from application
3. created Appspec.yml file as below

```
   version: 0.0
   os: windows
   files:
     - source: AdvertApiPublish.zip
       destination: C:\inetpub\wwwroot
```

i uploaded zip file including appspec file, and do deployment i got following error

> The deployment failed because an invalid version value (0.0) was entered in the application specification file. Make sure your AppSpec file specifies "0.0" as the version, and then try again.

on google i found this stackoverflow question
[AWS CodeDeploy ymal file error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43485953/aws-codedeploy-ymal-file-error)

i tried to change encoding also but no luck.
i dont know what i am missing

Comment: i tried putting "0.0" in string also as error said, but not resolved

Answer (score 1):

i could solve before install event issue, using below encoding in vs2019 community edition

[image]

but then after in install event i got following error
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen ... AdvertApiPublish.zip

that i knew it was sily error there, i dont have to set zip file in yaml file , i have to give published application directory inside it.
so i changed yaml file as below

```
version: 0.0
os: windows
files:
  - source: **PublishAdvertApi**
    destination: C:\inetpub\wwwroot
```

AND MY DEPLOYMENT WAS SUCCEEDED!! HURREEEE